# Moderator Means Table

Tags: interaction

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this table:

[image]

For example, do I interpret line 3 as a MOOSES_Rating of 5 is has a .07 effect size higher than the reference category? This difference isn't statistically significant at the 10% level, because the p-value is .281.

Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you generate this table (code) ? What are the underlying data ? Where did the data come from ? What is your research question(s) ? Unfortuntely we don't possess psychic powers here. Also, please do not post pictures of output. Post the output itself and use the ``` delimiters to format it.

Comment: Hi @Robert Long. Thank you for trying to help! I didn't create this table, so I cannot provide the code. For this same reason, I cannot post the output itself.  I'm having trouble interpreting this table. I'm sorry I'm not able to give you the information you asked for! If there are any resources to help read moderator means table generally, that would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: In applied statistics, *context* is vitally important. If you provide no context whatsoever you will receive very poor, if any, advice.

Comment: Thanks @Rober Long. If it helps, the MOOSES Rating is a measure of social-emotional learning measurement objectivity. So for example, 1 here indicates that it has a MOOSES Rating of 5, and 0 indicates that it does not have a Rating of 5. I think (this means that the average ES for MOOSES Rating 5 is .07, what does the p-value here tell me)? Thanks so much.

Comment: Or maybe it means that at the average ES for MOOSES Rating 4, .07 is the ES for MOOSES Rating 5. And then maybe the p-value is the largest probability of obtaining the test results if Rating 4 & 5 are actually the same? Thanks again Robert!

Comment: It could mean that. Then again it could be something different. So is this from a published paper ? If so I don't know.why you won't provide more details. If not then where did the data and table come from ? (I have already asked this and you said you can't answer, but then you went ahead and gave a bit more info anyway, which is very strange)

Comment: It would be better to edit your question with the additional information you supplied in comments, answers to more of @RobertLong questions and anything else you know and we do not.